Is it conceivable that carburettor icing alone could have caused the power loss?
A few days ago, one of our Club's planes, a Robin HR200, had to make an emergency landing shortly after T/O. It reached about 410ft AGL when it suddenly lost power, the FI took control from the P/UT and put it down in a field. The crew is fine, and the plane undamaged.
The current explanation of the CAMO is Carb Ice, which I'm struggling with. It'd be great to get some feedback from the hive mind as to what possible causes we should maybe continue to investigate.
Thus, the question is:
Is it conceivable that carburettor icing alone could have caused the incident?
The events and possibly relevant detail in order:
The plane was filled up in the morning and flew 89 minutes, with a stop at a different airfield, without issue. The P/UT had recently passed his first progresscheck and was supposed to begin pattern training. He had done a thorough preflight incl draining etc; which was overseen and double-checked by the FI.
Generally, the plane is maintained in a CAMO contract and was in service for just over 40 hours after its last 50hr check.
The engine was normal, although the FI reported that it took a second or two longer than normal (about 7 seconds), but that may have been due to the P/UT priming the engine differently. Presently I don't believe this is relevant.
All checklist items were completed and double-checked. Taxi with just the engine fuel pump was normal (the boost pump is off during taxi, but on for engine start and T/O).
The runup checklist for the HR200 is split into 2 parts. The first one contains set parking brake, T&P checks, Mixture rich, Mag check, Carb heat check etc. The second one safety items (seats, belts etc), trim settings, fuel pump on, flaps as required, lights, transponder etc.
In between those two, the crew briefed emergency procedures during T/O roll or initial climb which is standard in our club. This may have taken up to 2 minutes due to the experience of P/UT - this may be relevant as on line up the carb heat check would be around 2.5 min in the past, with the engine at around 1000 RPM since then.
The takeoff roll was normal. The student remembers double-checking the Throttle to be fully in, the FI remembers checking engine indications with everything being green. The FI can't remember the exact RPM but that the power and noise "felt" was normal, as was the rotation point.
Due to the wind, the FI requested the student to accelerate slightly beyond Vy to about 70 kn shortly after T/O which he did. Upon reaching the max Alt of 410 ft AGL, the engine suddenly lost power but kept running. The FI took control and changed the attitude to best glide. Carb heat was set before even checking Mixture, and was kept warm until touchdown. Mixture, primer, ignition etc were checked. There was no time to use a checklist but the FI had about 3200 hours, and several hundred on type, so I believe that everything sensible was done.
W/B was close to max (761 kg); CG about in the middle of the normal category at ~0.38.
WX was between these two metars, so RH about 80-85% at OAT of 8 Celsius.
1250Z 23011KT 9999 FEW020 08/04 Q1013
1420Z 24011KT 9999 -DZ SCT019 08/05 Q1014
After emergency responders left the scene, an engine test was performed about 3 hours after touchdown. The engine started, but ran very rough. The mixture was leaned out, and several seconds after that the engine appeared to "breathe" and began to run normally.
(I'm awaiting a more detailed recollection of how this test played out and will update the question - ie how long it took to start etc)
The next day, an engine inspection was performed. Spark plugs were replaced; the lower ones had some lead on them (which is reasonably normal with the O-235, generally they indicated a slightly rich mixture from the previous runs.
Now I need to positively exclude any possibility other than carb icing, which is my struggle with the explanation. I cannot let return a plane to service (one of our main trainers), if there is a chance for a different, latent problem.
It's thinkable that the throttle valve accreted some ice in the runup area, but only to the extent that the difference in power after full throttle would not be evident to a highly experienced FI, and the ground run according to the PowerFlarm readout was normal (although it only records every 4 seconds, so it's not super accurate).
If there was icing initially, it's further thinkable that further ice accreted to the existing one with the throttle fully open. However, in that case I would have expected a gradual, not sudden, decrease of power, at least over a period of a few seconds. The plane did not fly through any visible moisture, so icing of the air filter can be excluded. Also, using carb heat would have immediately rectified such a problem.
How can I reconcile icing with the sudden loss of power around 40-45 seconds into the flight? Carb heat was turned on almost immediately, and kept on until touchdown approximately 1 min and 5-10 seconds later.
Initially, my first thought was a vacuum lock in the tank or downstream, with a reduced airflow to the tanks. That would be consistent with the FI's feeling of the engine running better with reduced power, she was smoothly alternating the power lever from full to idle and back. The accelerator pump, when putting power back in, appeared to give a short boost of power albeit for a very short time before returning to rough running.
Please comment additional questions for me to investigate below; I shall try to reply and update this post with answers or additional clarification where required.

The site is not supposed to be used to collect opinions, it works on a closed question / factual answer model. What is your question?

The question is whether Carb icing could be the sole cause of the incident. I'll try to rephrase my question accordingly. Thank you for the comment

Speculation on the causes of accidents that are still under investigation are specifically off-topic here. See [help/on-topic]. FWIW, loss of power at 400ft AGL is a serious problem that has to be dealt with immediately, whatever the cause. The instructor did exactly the right thing and the aircraft and crew are safe. For the rest, we wait for the official report.

It wasn't an accident, it was an incident @CatchAsCatchCan, and there's isn't an official investigation.

I also feel like we can't give anything but opinion here, and so there's no "right" answer. I'll refrain from voting to close, but if I was a normal user I probably would.

Unfortunately speculation is all I have left; the authorities will not investigate. I am the accountable manager for our A/C. If someone could point me towards a more suitable forum with the same level of experience I'd appreciate it, and would then even support a vote to close

This was a case of carburettor icing. Conditions were in the regime of high probability of carburettor icing in any power setting. All aviators should know this!

@Jpe61 I'm glad you are so sure. At full power, with a normal takeoff run an initial climb, followed by a sudden power loss of (calculated) 1400+ RPM. I shall be interested to learn what you think exactly happened technically there with the ice. That's the kind of explanation that I'd be after. Of course every aviator knows what carb icing is, your comment comes across slightly offensive.

Would you agree with my comment though? As per the question carb heat was not on during t/o. This is clearly a mistake, since OAT of 8°C and dewpoint of 4 is very much a heavy carb icing condition, and not vapor lock condition at all. Water in fuel was checked twice, none found. No anomalies detected in engine inspection. Use occam's razor.

@Jpe61 Unfortunately I cannot. Having Carb heat on with full power is more likely to generate detonation inside the cylinders than prevent icing.  You are right with regards to the conditions, which I happily agree to - on any lower than full power carb heat must be applied.
A locked valve or reduced pressure relief to the fuel tank is high on my list of suspects to check, too. Carb heat I find hard to align with what happened.

@ExternalUse but icing could have caused an excessive lean setting, causing engine failure at 400 feet from overheating, or from excessively rich.  Is there any data on cylinder head temps?  Did the engine have enough oil?  How long was carbon heat ON during runup?

@RobertDiGiovanni Oil was sufficient; T's & P's were green. No CHT data (very simple trainer A/C). But, as of yesterday icing is prettys much off the table - it ran fine in the lower RPM regions but reasonably rough with some misfires in the higher power regions. Unless the mechanic who checked it over, replaced the spark plugs etc introduced something new (ie forgot a cable or sth - it's field surgery after all) then I believe the report of the initial run on the evening of that landing to be wrong or incomplete, there's definitely sth off. I'll write a comment here once I know the result.

As phrased, this question is answerable but hardly helpful... is it conceivable that carb icing...?  Sure, it's conceivable. All sorts of things are conceivable. Doesn't mean that they're likely, or that one of them is what actually happened. Maybe a more discussion-oriented board like PPRune would have a forum where this could be kicked around at greater length, but as it stands, this question & its comments have exactly the sort of speculations that show why it's a terrible fit for this site, and will remain closed.

@RalphJ please see the comment thread below the answer; I've already accepted that. But thanks for the suggestion on the forum, that's actually helpful.

You are right to question the carb heat explanation, I'm not buying that either given your detailed timeline. Carb heat can definitely cause an engine failure, but usually there's going to be a power loss first. Also, given carb heat had been on as part of the run-up checks a few minutes before its unlikely enough ice had a chance to accumulate.
After an engine failure due to carb icing the residual heat from the engine will almost always melt the remaining carb ice, and the engine sparks to life immediately. You say the engine ran rough at first, which is more consistent with a case of fuel contamination. So, that's is a more likely explanation than icing.
Whichever the case, I'd be on the instructors like a rash, as it seems possible someone was lax about carb heat or draining the tanks. Even if that isn't the explanation it does not hurt to use this incident as a reminder to be diligent.

In the absence of a full investigation, which is not going to happen, we have to look at likelihoods and see what improvements could be made for safety. The stated reason of carb icing is less likely than another explanation which fits the information in the question. While I accept that I cannot give a definitive answer of what exactly caused the failure, I can certainly suggest actions which will improve safety down the line.

Thanks @GdD, I've discussed a few improvements with our HT already. Here for example, the crew didn't observe the RPM before and after applying Carb heat during the runup; something I learned differently for example (I still call out "no rise, no ice" to myself). Carb ice certainly is a possibility, and likely a contributing factor. It's just sad (but accepted, of course) that they can't be discussed in a forum full of intelligent people from the industry.

@ExternalUse I understand your frustration, but Stack Exchange is not a forum, and in your case, the strict policies regarding questions are against you.

Understood, and accepted.
